# Computing Eigen Values, Eigen Vectors using OpenCV

Tags: c++, python, opencv, scipy

I'm having trouble in calculating **Eigen Vectors, Values in OpenCV**. I have done the same in Python (SciPy) but I'm having trouble in **porting my code**.

I have a 2 Matrices **Sw, Sb** whose values are:

```
Sw:[0.0112962962962963, 0.00675925925925926;
  0.00675925925925926, 0.007962962962962963]
Sb:[0.0530787037037037, 0.01657407407407407;
  0.01657407407407407, 0.004606481481481482]
```

For above values of Sw, Sb, **computing Eigen Values, Eigen Vectors in SciPy (Python) using the following**:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import linalg as la
evals,evecs = la.eig(Sw,Sb)
```

**yields the following:**

```
evals:
[ 0.17299805+0.j -8.47412141+0.j]
evecs:
[[ 1.         -0.31926401]
 [-0.54311321  1.        ]]
```

**I'm trying to port the above code to OpenCV (C++ API)**

For the same values of Sw, Sb, **computing Eigen Values and Eigen Vectors in OpenCV** using

```
cv::eigen(Sb,Sb_Eig_Val,Sb_Eig_Vec);
```

yields **different values** which is:

```
Sb_Eig_Val
[0.05820394496612978; -0.0005187597809445917]
Sb_Eig_Vec
[0.9553644860284983, 0.2954296850952915;
  -0.2954296850952915, 0.9553644860284983]
```

**Am I missing something here?**

Comment: Please edit your question to ask what you're actually interested in knowing.

Comment: This question might fit slightly better in [scicomp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're solving two different linear algebra problems! Consider:

```
from scipy import linalg as la
sw=[[0.0112962962962963, 0.00675925925925926],[0.00675925925925926, 0.007962962962962963]]
sb=[[0.0530787037037037, 0.01657407407407407],[0.01657407407407407, 0.004606481481481482]]
print la.eig(sb)
```

Which gives:

```
(array([ 0.05820394+0.j, -0.00051876+0.j]), array([[ 0.95536449, -0.29542969],
   [ 0.29542969,  0.95536449]]))
```

exactly as openCV. In the `scipy` case with [two input arguments](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.linalg.decomp.html#eig) you are solving the generalized eigenvalue problem, but with only one argument it assumes the other matrix is the identity (this is typically what we mean when we say diagonalization)

Since the matrices are symmetric, you should be using `eigh` in scipy. Real symmetric matrices give real eigenpairs, and it will stop returning a complex number.